# Using jq to filter children and keep only specific key

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to delete all entries that do not have any dependencies, but as I don't know jq very well, I'm having a problem with finding the answer.

I have:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "Alpha": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Gamma",
        "Delta"
      ],
      "other_value_1": [
        "aaa"
      ],
      "other_value_n": [
        "unknown number of other values"
      ]
    },
    "Beta": {
      "package_name": "some name",
      "scm": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git url"
      }
    },
    "Gamma": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Delta"
      ]
    },
    "Delta": {
      "dependencies": []
    }
  }
}
```

Out of which I want to get only the names of objects with dependencies (in this example: Alpha, Gamma) and the dependencies themself:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "Alpha": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Gamma",
        "Delta"
      ]
    },
    "Gamma": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Delta"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let's assume that there may be many unforeseen values besides dependencies

Comment: So your expected output is just the keys of which dependencies is set and not empty? Eg: `Alpha,Gamma`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using the [Object construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction%3A%7B%7D) shortcut `{name}`:

```bash
jq '.dev |= ({Alpha, Gamma} | .[] |= {dependencies})'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JzBjJhixUbM)

If the keys filtered should be dynamic, selecting on `has(0)` can test for the existence of a first array item, i.e. for a non-empty list:

```bash
jq '.dev[] |= ({dependencies} | select(.[] | has(0)))'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/co1nvl_cTc3)

Output:

```json
{
  "dev": {
    "Alpha": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Gamma",
        "Delta"
      ]
    },
    "Gamma": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Delta"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more verbose way, without specifying the keys:

```
.dev |= with_entries(select(.value.dependencies | length > 0) | .value = { dependencies: .value.dependencies})
```

Using [`with_entires()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) those where `.value.dependencies` has `length > 0`, then [set (`|=`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=) `value` to an object only containing the `dependencies`

---

Will output:

```json
{
  "dev": {
    "Alpha": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Gamma",
        "Delta"
      ]
    },
    "Gamma": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Delta"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vuHZSfv5eTx)

Comment: Output is the same as OP's example? Not sure what you mean by only the names.

Comment: Mm not quite sure if that is what op want. "I'm delete all entries that do not have any dependencies" indicates to me that OP want't some sort of dynamic solution, but maybe only output the keys themself. I'll wait for OP to clarify!

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. Sorry for spelling, I was in a hurry when posting yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Here's another understandable solution, which constructs a new object from scratch:

```
{
    dev: .dev | map_values({dependencies} | select(.[][0]))
}
```

It first builds an object containing only the dependencies per key and then selects only those with at least one item.

Output:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "Alpha": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Gamma",
        "Delta"
      ]
    },
    "Gamma": {
      "dependencies": [
        "Delta"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```